# Do I a need a DATV for arrival and departure at LHR by same airline same terminal same day?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, datv, dutch-residents

I am an Indian and have residence permit in Netherlands. I am planning to a book a flight with British Airways from Amsterdam to Bangalore via London Heathrow. I will have a layover of approx 2 hours in LHR Arrival and Departure terminal is same (Terminal 5)

Do I still need Direct Airside Transit Visa ?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y?

Comment: Please write places in full. Sometimes NL means Netherlands but sometimes [Newfoundland and Labrador](https://www.newfoundlandlabrador.com/)